# Sort Integer 3D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, 3d, sum

I'm trying to sort input in C but I keep on getting the wrong answer and I can't identify my error. I'm trying to use the simple bubble sort technique.

This is my code:

```
#define SIZE 100

int main() {

char input[MAXSIZE];

int dummy[MAXSIZE];

int sequenceNumber[MAXSIZE];
int tracker=-1;

int array[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];

int set=-1;
int sequence=-1;

int counter=-1;
int temp=0;



while (1==1) {
   if (fgets(input, MAXSIZE-1, stdin) == NULL){
     printf("Invalid Input");
     break;
   }else {

     char* s;

     for (s = input; (*s != '\n') && isspace(*s); s++){
        continue; 
     }

     if (*s == '\n'){

        continue;

     } else if (*s == 'f'){

        break; 

     } else if (*s == 'S'){

        set++;
        sequence=-1;

     } else{

        sscanf(input, "%d: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &dummy[0], &dummy[1], &dummy[2], &dummy[3], &dummy[4], &dummy[5]);
        sequence++;
        array[set][sequence][0]=dummy[0];
        array[set][sequence][1]=dummy[1]+dummy[2]+dummy[3]+dummy[4]+dummy[5];

        if (sequence==0){
            tracker++;
        }
        sequenceNumber[tracker]=sequence+1;

     }

   }
}


for (int i=0;i<set; i++){
    for (int j=0;j<tracker;j++){
        counter++;
        for (int k=0; k<sequenceNumber[counter];k++){
            if (array[i][k][1]<array[i][k+1][1])
                temp=array[i][k][1];
                array[i][k][1]=array[i][k+1][1];
                array[i][k][0]=array[i][k+1][0];
                array[i][k+1][1]=temp;
        }
    }
 }


for (int i=0; i<=set;i++){
    printf("\n");
    printf("SET %d\n",i+1);
    for (int j=0;j<tracker;j++){
        counter++;
        for (int k=0; k<sequenceNumber[counter];k++){
            printf("%d %d\n",array[i][k][0],array[i][k][1]);
        }
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

On the input:

```
SET 1

1: 5,5,6,5
2: 3,4,5,5
3: 3,4,5,6

SET 2

1: 5,7,8,7
2: 5,5,5,6


finish
```

I get:

```
SET 1 
2 17
3 18

SET 2
```

Instead of:

```
SET 1
2 17
3 18
1 21

SET 2 
1 27
2 21
```

Can somebody please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm basically trying to sort my dimensional array in ascending order of sum for each sequence number within each set. Any sort of help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are not resetting         `counter` before using it in second for loop.

Comment: 4Mb may or may not be too large for the stack, depending on system. You really shouldn't allocate it there. See the linked duplicate to your previous question for alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Set `counter=-1` between your two for loops.

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it made no difference. :( Thank you.

Comment: I have done it on my computer between the two for loops and it's works.

Comment: Which for loop do you mean?

Comment: Between your two main `for` loops.